# Add dynamic html to angular component

Tags: angular

I have an angular component which is similar to textEditor(contentEditable div) . It has it's html template. Now based on what user typed , I want to add some dynamic html as well. Something like this:-

```
<span class="macro consolas-text" (click)="OpenPopup()"></span>
```

I am able to add this html dynamically to my html template but I am unable to call this function "OpenPopup". I think angular is unable to identify this span since this was added dynamically.

How can I make it work?

Comment: How did you add that html snippet dynamically to the html template? Maybe the function you used didn't add it like you thought it did.

Comment: I am just creating this entire span using string concatenation. I am not using any of the document.createElement() and other operations. This is an existing code and it used to work in angular 1 but OpenPopup() was not sitting in angular controller or service. It was a pure javascript function. This is breaking when migration from angular 1 to angular 2.

Comment: How did your angular 1 project know where to look to find the `OpenPopup()` function? Could you emulate that process for Angular 2?

Comment: It's an angularjs attribute directive that creates a dynamic html based on what user has entered in textbox. we were not using ng-click but onclick="OpenPopup()". This was working since this OpenPopup() function is present in global scope as it's a pure javascript function.

Comment: Could you access the `OpenPopup()` function in your component's class? You'll could try `declare function OpenPopup;` and then using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML property binding, if you are assigning a variable

```
<span class="macro consolas-text" (click)="OpenPopup('sometext')" [innerHTML]="sometext"></span>
```

If you want to assign some text , use `' '`

```
<span class="macro consolas-text" (click)="OpenPopup('sometext')" [innerHTML]="'some text'"></span>
```

Comment: I didn't get this . Can you please explain more. My question is about Invoking OpenPopUp() function.

Comment: can you share the value in the variable `sometext`.  you need to pass some content to popup? or what is the expected output?

Comment: doesn't matter. I just want to invoke the function. Updated question.

Comment: where is the `OpenPopup()` method is present? can you elaborate?

Comment: it's in my-component.ts assuming my component name is my-component

Comment: assuming `app-component` has `my-component` and now you need to pass content to `my-comp` from the `app-comp` correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144098/discussion-between-user911-and-aravind).